# Checking for Last Name, First Name from one Table to Another

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, vb.net, t-sql

Hey all This is my situation. I have a 2012 MS SQL database that have the following tables:

> -Schedule_2_16_2016
>
> -EmployeeInfo

The **Schedule_2_16_2016** is created with a different program and I am only able to parse the information out and save it into that database **from a PDF**.

The employee names in the **Schedule_2_16_2016** table look like this:

```
empName                |Date_Started |
-----------------------|-------------| 
Barker, Bob            | 1/12/2014   |
Gill, Sam Marco        | 1/1/2014    |
Scott, Greg D.         | 12/14/2014  |
Gates, Bill            | 5/19/2014   |
Jobs, Steve            | 8/18/2014   |
Allred, Nick E. (Elly) | 7/28/2015   |
Nuc, Ted               | 9/18/2015   |
```

The Employee names in the **EmployeeInfo** table (That I control) look like this:

```
empName       |FName  |LName   |
--------------|-------|--------|
Bob Barker    | Bob   | Barker |
Sam Gill      | Sam   | Gill   |
Greg Scott    | Greg  | Scott  |
Bill Gates    | Bill  | Gates  |
Steve Jobs    | Steve | Jobs   |
Elly Allred   | Elly  | Allred |
Ted Nuc       | Ted   | Nuc    |
```

Notice how my version does not have the middle name and *some* dont have nicknames like the **Schedule_2_16_2016** table does.

How can I go about an **inner join** and find the correct employee even though **some** of the names will not match up with each other?

The MS SQL query code I am currently using is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [store1234].[dbo].[Schedule_2_16_2016] AS empSchedule
INNER JOIN [store1234].[dbo].[EmployeeInfo] AS empInfo 
   ON empInfo.empName = empSchedule.empName
WHERE empSchedule.empName LIKE '%Gill, Sam%'
```

This comes up with no records which it should have the record but like I said, it's calling it (in the example above) **Sam Gill** instead of **Gill, Same Marco** or **Elly Allred** instead of **Allred, Nick E. (Elly)**.

Is there any type of RegEX or something that I can use in order to combine the needed 2 tables together for *any 1 person* in the **WHERE** clause?

Comment: Is this a one time task, or would it recur?

Comment: Where does the parameter '%Gill, Sam%' come from? Is there any flexibility with that?

Comment: @plutonix it's recur

Comment: It's complicated and if you got a million rows like that to find pair I doubt you can cover all cases because it depends a lot on (not normalized) human input. You need to create a lot of condition (match a fname+lname with all possible names from a row). A tip I can give is: flag each **EmployeeInfo** you find to looks like a match. IMHO you can create a relation table with some sort of "likeless to be" column to rank the probability you found a correct match for that pair of data

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL should look like this, but still there is no guaranty you get the right result, unless you address all possible conditions.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [store1234].[dbo].[Schedule_2_16_2016] AS empSchedule
INNER JOIN [store1234].[dbo].[EmployeeInfo] AS empInfo 
   ON CHARINDEX(empInfo.LName + ', ' + empInfo.FName, empSchedule.empName) = 1
```

Comment: Doing that query gave me 85 rows out of the 155 that are on the schedule so i dont think that was the correct one.

Comment: @StealthRT, As I mentioned, there might be many different exceptions. you need to change the query to cover all the exceptions. Find you which records are not fall into the result of my query and figure out why. and continue doing that until you cover all the records. there is no perfect answer for your problem as we don't see all the data. Good luck :)

Comment: Would you happen to know a query I can run along side this one to let me know the ones that didnt make the cut?

Comment: Change the =1 to <>1 then you'll see what is not match

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you plan to handle middle names when present, since `EmployeeInfo` doesn't include that field in the table, but this will get the ones with nicknames in `empSchedule.empName` **if** they're **all** enclosed in parentheses **and** have a matching `empInfo.FName` like your sample data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Schedule_2_16_2016] AS empSchedule,
[dbo].[EmployeeInfo] AS empInfo 
    WHERE
        CHARINDEX(empInfo.LName + ', ' + empInfo.FName, empSchedule.empName) = 1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Schedule_2_16_2016] AS empSchedule,
[dbo].[EmployeeInfo] AS empInfo
    WHERE 
        CHARINDEX(empInfo.LName  + ', ', empSchedule.empName) = 1
    AND
    (STUFF(
        STUFF(
                empSchedule.empName, 
                CHARINDEX(')', empSchedule.empName),
                LEN(empSchedule.empName), ''), 
                1, 
                CHARINDEX('(', empSchedule.empName), '')
    ) = empInfo.FName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:-

```
select * from empSchedule t1 
inner join empInfo t2 
on t1.empName like t2.LName+', '+t2.FName+'%'
WHERE t1.empName LIKE '%Gill, Sam%'
```